# Layout of command output executed automatically in PuTTY from a batch file is broken

Tags: batch-file, cmd, putty, htk

I have followed this question to build a batch file to run the PuTTYwith my username and password:
[How to run a command file in PuTTY using automatic login in a command prompt?](https://superuser.com/q/515601/213663)

---

```
@echo off
START putty.exe -ssh [domain] -l [username] -pw [password] -m code.txt
@echo
```

And the PuTTY will try to run the `code.txt` file, which have the following code:

```
HResults -p -e "???" sil -e "???" sp -L labels/test lib/words3 results/*.rec
read
```

It will show a matrix. I try to run the batch file, it is able to open PuTTY, login and run the command in text file. But the output in PuTTY terminal is a mess. The layout of output is fine, when I doing those things manually. Is that mean some kind of setting is missing? It's not making any sense a batch file will change the output of another application...... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-m` switch imply a non-interactive session. While, when logging in manually, an interactive mode is used by default.

It may fundamentally affect output of some applications.

Try forcing the interactive mode using the [`-t` switch](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-pty):

```
START putty.exe -ssh [domain] -t -l [username] -pw [password] -m code.txt
```